# AS3 referencing Singleton

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, reference, singleton

I have a GameEngine class which is a sprite, and a GameModel which is a Singleton and holds a lot of the data.

I then get the data with

```
GameModel.getInstance().variable;
```

my game engine has a lot of them in it now and i was wondering if it would be more efficient if i had a reference to the GameModel in my GameEngine instead of creating it all the time

```
private var _data:GameModel = GameModel.getInstance();
trace(_data.variable);
```

I have a pretty strong feeling it will be more efficient but if anyone could let me know for sure and let me know if you can potentially see flaws with this method that would be much appreciated, cheers, rory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely a good idea to store the instance in a property, since the lookup will be faster, but also because it lowers the GameEngine's knowledge of the GameModel's implementation details.

For example, imagine you've got a bunch of `GameModel.getInstance()` calls inside your GameEngine class and you decide to drop the singleton behaviour. You'll be rewriting all those calls, however if you'd cached the instance in a property you'd only need to rewrite one line.

That said, forget about singletons altogether, they're a far greater evil than premature optimization, but if you MUST use one, at least store the instance in a property in your client classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly add it as an instance, but I doubt it would make a noticeable difference. Premature optimization is the root of all evil and that :)

If you are really curious you should try to benchmark it and see if it actually changes anything.

EDIT: Oh yes, as the other answer here mentions - might want to drop singletons altogether. I would recommend looking at swiftsuspenders https://github.com/tschneidereit/SwiftSuspenders/ for dependency injection (or even robotlegs, for a great light-weight MVC solution, including swiftsuspenders).

Comment: Thanks for your response Jonatan! 
just did a quick test looped 100,000 times
_data.speed += _data.speedAcceleration;  57MS

Comment: And compared to the other version?

Comment: i accidently hit enter instead of shift enter before adding the other results!! 
GameModel.getInstance().speed += GameModel.getInstance().speedAcceleration; 122MS